# file not found during import csv to mysql db table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import, ftp

the folders structure of my site is the following: www.mysite.it/site/scripts.

At this path there are two files: import.php and tabella.csv.

tabella.csv is a CSV file like this:

```
"2016-09-02", 100.01, 4005.09, 5000, 1.09, 120.09, 100.5, 200.77
"2016-09-03", 150.01, 4205.09, 5600, 1.10, 150.09, 300.5,300.77
```

import.php is the PHP script to execute te import and it's a file like this:

```
<?php

    $csvFile = "../scripts/tabella.csv";

    $db = @mysql_connect('****', '****', '****');
    @mysql_select_db('******');

    $query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \' '. $csvFile .' \' INTO TABLE rame
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\' 
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (
            giorno,
            lmedollton,
            changedolleuro,
            euroton,
            lmesterton,
            delnotiz,
            girm,
            sgm
        )';
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($db);

?>
```

The error is 'file not found': I tried to use 'tabella.csv' and the the realpath also (using realpath PHP function) but the error is always the same. Which is the correct string that I have to assign to $csvFile variable? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Did you check file permissions?

Comment: @Andreas, CSV file permissions are setted to 777

Comment: It might be that your server does not allow `LOCAL` in a `LOAD DATA INFILE` query, as this might pose a security risk (cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: so can I do the import?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an absolute path to your csv file e.g.

```
$csvFile = "/var/www/htdocs/site/scripts/tabella.csv"
```

because mysql will not be able to resolve the path relative to apache httpdoc-root directory. See also the [Mysql-Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the
>   client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full
>   path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path
>   name, the name is interpreted **relative to the directory in which the
>   client program was started**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already tried with absolute path and the file results always not found..

Comment: When webserver and database server are the same you can try without LOCAL with absolute path, does that work?

Comment: ... and check if the mysql-user has permission to read the file

Comment: thanks.. I've already try it but result was the same.. How can I set mysql-user permissions? many thanks..

Comment: do you have console/ssh access to the server? If so you can try to put the csv file into the /tmp dir first and see if that works. To check if mysql can read this file you need to find out the user under which mysql is running, and login as that user and try to cat/less that file, e.g.: `su - mysql` and `cat /path/to/tabella.csv`